# Should I get instances of classes in onResume() or onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My intuition says to do it once in `onCreate()`, but I am not sure if there is some advantage to having a fresh instance each time. What's the best practice here?

Comment: What classes? What instances? It dependes on what you want. `onCreate()` runs everytime the `Activity` it's created but if it's paused when you come back it won't run.`onResume()` runs everytime the `Activity` gets the focus. Imagine your app needs network connection, may be you want to check you have connectivity `onResume()` to prevent people disabling it during your game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need some more context to give you a straight answer. Both methods might be called multiple times depending on what the user is doing.

I suggest defaulting your object instances as null, and inside `onCreate()` and/or `onResume()`, initialize it only if it is null.

```
if(objectInstance == null)
{
    objectInstance = new MyObject();
}
```

Comment: In my case I am initiating WifiManager. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: I am also using an app specific class I named `Wifi` where I store the list from `WifiManager`'s `getScanResults()`. I get the results from the `MainActivity` and access them in a list fragment (Is this bad practice?). I am worried that if I use `if (instance == null)` the list will not be updated with new results.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these `Wifi` or `WifiManager` classes, but instead you could do: `if (instance == null || instance.needToUpdateResults())` you will need to define that second method.

Comment: I apologize but I wouldn't know what to put in the need update method

Comment: Well, what did you mean by your words "I am worried ...the list will not be updated with new results" when does it need to be updated with new results? That is what the method I'm suggesting should return, `true` if you need to update the wifi object instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not re instantiate an object that you already have unless you have a reason for it! recreating objects just gets more memory and produces more garbage for the GC that is bad for efficiency!

So initialize needed objects in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Like Hojjat points out you should not re instantiate objects, you must create again the objects if they are not currently present,

```
if(myObject == null){
    myObject = new ObjectFoo();
}
```

but if you are using a service maybe that will require the initialization:

```
class A extends Activity{
    public ServiceClass mService = null; // service objecct
    public void onCreate(){
        mService = new ServiceClass();
    }

    public void onResume(){
        mService.methodA();
    }
}
```